# Recording a Slow-Motion video with Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, mobile

I have been searching for a while but all answers/questions are either very old or suggest things like recording normal video and converting it.

What I need to do is allow users to record a slow-motion video which will then be processed by the app and analyzied.

The app is in flutter so a flutter solution is preferable but we can also go with a native solution.